# How to set id's to labels using for loop in python without using the kv file?

Tags: python, for-loop, kivy, ids

i have figured out how to add multiple labels to a grid in the python file but i'm struggling to add ids to those labels in the for loop. I tried the following but that doesn't seem to work. Please also guide me to access those labels using the ids. Any help or guidance is highly appreciated. Thank you

```
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Builder.load_file("gridtable.kv")

class MyBox(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        pass
        # for i in range(48):
        #     self.b = TextInput(multiline=False, font_size=dp(30))
        #     self.mygrid.add_widget(self.b)

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols=6
        self.textinputs = {}
        for i in range(48):
            key = i+1
            self.textinputs[key] = TextInput(multiline=False,font_size=dp(30),on_text=self.calc(key))
            self.add_widget(self.textinputs[key])
        
    def calc(self,key):
        print(self.textinputs[key])

        
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyBox()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

```
<MyBox>:
    mygrid:my_grid
    orientation: "vertical"
    MyGrid:
        id: my_grid
        size_hint: 1,0.8
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint: 1,0.2
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Button: 
                text: "Expense Total:"
            Button: 
                text: "Revenue Total:"    
        Button:
            text: "Profit:"
            font_size: 40
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Users\jaika\OneDrive\Desktop\python\lil_curry_project\gridtable.py", line 38, in <module>
     MyApp().run()        

     print(self.textinputs[key])
 KeyError: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried the following but that doesn't seem to work.

When something doesn't work you should post the details of how/why it fails. For instance, does it crash with a traceback?

> Please also guide me to access those labels using the ids

The `id` used by kivy is set only via kv language, it has specific behaviour local to the kv rule in which it is set.

Since you're creating the widgets in python you don't need to set an id, you can store them in a list or a dictionary or anything else you like. For instance, you could set `self.textinputs = {}` then for each one `self.textinputs[i] = TextInput(...); self.add_widget(self.textinputs[i])`.

Comment: This is exactly what i need and i'll remember about the traceback. Although this makes me run into another complication. i'm trying to make a function which makes basic calculations based on the textinput data but i don't know how to pass that particulat textbox in that function coz the textbox doesn't really know its dict key unlike ids, and the on_text property is also not working as expected. i've edited the code below forloop for more details

Comment: I recommend asking a new question rather than adding things to this one, you'll get more attention that way. But in general you can attach more data to the textbox in many different ways, e.g. subclassing it and adding your own `identifier_string` StringProperty (although this is not the only option and may not be the best depending on context).